# Jquery Annotate / PHP error by sending the object value

Tags: ajax

Send var annotation_id:

```
echo $json = json_encode(array('annotation_id'=>$save[0]));
```

Get var annotation_id:

```
if (image.useAjax) {
      $.ajax({
           url: image.saveUrl,
           data: form.serialize(),
           error: function(e) { 
             alert("An error occured saving that note.");
           },
           success: function(data) {
                 if (data.annotation_id != undefined) {
                     editable.note.id = data.annotation_id;                         
                     alert(editable.note.id);
                }
          },
          dataType: "json"
       });
 }
```

So...what's wrong with my code ?
Not getting the value of this variable.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information? What's happening when you run this? Do you get an error?

Comment: always the error, I can get the value of the variable.when you run falls on alert ("An error occurred saving That note.");

Comment: Have you tried manually accessing the url the ajax call points to, and does it return the proper value? Also, take a look at the "e" variable in the error callback, it may provide you with more information.